# incorrect header check while implementing GZIP in spring boot REST APIs

Tags: compression, gzip, geojson, large-data, http-compression

I'm working on the REST APIs(Spring boot), dealing with **large size responses**(around 15mb). I want to reduce the response size and by compressing it using **GZIP**.

These are the request headers(through postman)-

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

Content-Type: application/json
```

My application.properties

```
server.compression.enabled=true

server.compression.mime-types=application/json,application/geo+json

server.compression.gzip.level=1
```

Following is my controller code to return large size response by compressing it using GZIP.

```
    @GetMapping("/get")
    @Operation(operationId="OP_ID", summary = "API_SUMMARY", description  =  "ENDOPINT_DESCRIPTION")
    @ApiResponses(value = { 
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Response on success", content = { @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = FeatureCollection.class)) }),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "4XX/5XX", description = "Response on failure", content = {@Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = ApiErrorResponseObject.class))}) })
public ResponseEntity<FeatureCollection> getCycleData(String cycleId, String country) throws Exception  {
//Code to fetch 'featureCollection'
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_ENCODING, "gzip"); // Enable Gzip compression
        return new ResponseEntity<FeatureCollection>(featureCollection, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I'm seeing this error in postman-

**Error: incorrect header check**